# Powershell parameter error 'p'

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried typing this command

```
mkdir -p lol\hit\xx
```

But I get an error message

```
mkdir: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'p' is ambiguous.
```

I am following a tutorial online and according to that, there shouldn't be any error.
What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Read up on mkdir params here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkdir

Comment: Are you running the command in PowerShell?

Comment: @ne1410s it says if the directory exists there will be an error, but in my case it doesn't. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, I am

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mkdir, when run in PowerShell, runs as an alias to New-Item. This can be seen by running `Get-Help mkdir` within PowerShell.

In that case -p is ambiguous because it could be either of the `-Path` or `-PipelineVariable` arguments for New-Item. I believe that what you want is:

```
mkdir -path lol\hit\xx
```

That will create the lol folder at your current location, and the hit folder inside it, and the xx folder inside of that.

The -p switch for mkdir in Unix forces the command to create all folders needed to get to the path you designate (so if all you had was 'lol' it would creates the 'hit' folder within that, and then create the 'xx' folder within the 'hit' folder). PowerShell's New-Item does this by default.

Comment: Fixed it for me. Started receiving the error after updating to Windows 8.1 (-p was working fine on Windows 7).