# PowerShell PSObject confusion between -pass & -passthru

Tags: json, powershell, psobject

```
function getinfo {
    $strComputer = "localhost"
    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
    $Items1 = $colItems | Select DHCPServer, Caption, DNSHostName, IPAddress
    $Items2 = $colItems | Select ServiceName, MacAddress, IPSubnet, InterfaceIndex
}
$objects = (New-Object PSObject |
               add-member -pass NoteProperty "DHCP Server" $Items1.DHCPServer |
               add-member -pass NoteProperty "IP Address" $Items1.IPAddress | 
               add-member -passthru NoteProperty "Mac Address" $Items2.MacAddress | 
               add-member -passthru NoteProperty "IP Subnet" $Items2.IPSubnet
                )
$objects | ConvertTo-Json
```

I am confused about the `-pass` & `-passthru` keys. What's the difference, and why does nothing get populated when `-passthru` is used for `$Items1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell parameter error 'p'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128180/powershell-parameter-error-p)

Comment: The dupe I found was not perfect. The answer explains that parameters are ambiguous as a feature. It means the exact same thing in your case.

Comment: A good article is here: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/02/05/pstip-argument-disambiguation-in-powershell-3-0/

Comment: That explains. However, I am still confused as to how it failed at first and was successful when I changed to -pass.

Comment: You are even taking advantage of this with `GWMI -cl` which is short for `-class`. I don't know why it didnt work the first time. Your code is odd. Why did you split up the results of the query into 2 variables. Are you able to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with `-pass` or `-passthru`. The issue is that variables created inside a function are typically only available while that function is still running. From the help for [about_Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx):

> Windows PowerShell protects access to variables, aliases, functions,
>   and Windows PowerShell drives (PSDrives) by limiting where they can be
>   read and changed.

If you call the function by [using dot-source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/10/how-to-reuse-windows-powershell-functions-in-scripts.aspx) then you can keep the variables available for use in the `New-Object` command.

```
function getinfo {
    $strComputer = "localhost"
    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
    $Items1 = $colItems | Select DHCPServer, Caption, DNSHostName, IPAddress
    $Items2 = $colItems | Select ServiceName, MacAddress, IPSubnet, InterfaceIndex
}
. getinfo
$objects = (New-Object PSObject |
               add-member -pass NoteProperty "DHCP Server" $Items1.DHCPServer |
               add-member -pass NoteProperty "IP Address" $Items1.IPAddress | 
               add-member -passthru NoteProperty "Mac Address" $Items2.MacAddress | 
               add-member -passthru NoteProperty "IP Subnet" $Items2.IPSubnet
                )
$objects | ConvertTo-Json
```